# IndexOutOfRangeException when changing selected TabItem twice

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, tabcontrol, outofrangeexception

I have the following simple WPF-app:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlOutOfRangeException.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, IsAsync=True}" />
</Window>
```

with following simple code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TabControlOutOfRangeException
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public List<string> ItemsSource { get; private set; }
        public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ItemsSource = new List<string>{"Foo", "Bar", "FooBar"};

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the second tab ("Bar"), nothing is displayed. When I click again on any tab, I get an IndexOutOfRangeException. Setting IsAsync to False, the TabControl works.

Unfortunately, I have the requirement to query the user a "Save changes?" question when he leaves the current tab. So I wanted to set the SelectedIndex back to the old value within the set-property. Obviously this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

### Update

I've subclassed the TabControl with the evil hack and it works for me. Here is the code of MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlOutOfRangeException.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:TabControlOutOfRangeException="clr-namespace:TabControlOutOfRangeException" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControlOutOfRangeException:PreventChangingTabsTabControl
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
            CanChangeTab="{Binding CanChangeTab}" Margin="0,0,0,51" />
        <CheckBox Content="CanChangeTab" IsChecked="{Binding CanChangeTab}" Margin="0,287,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TabControlOutOfRangeException
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
        public List<string> ItemsSource { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ItemsSource = new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar", "FooBar" };

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private bool _canChangeTab;
        public bool CanChangeTab
        {
            get { return _canChangeTab; }
            set
            {
                _canChangeTab = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CanChangeTab");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the subclassed TabControl:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TabControlOutOfRangeException
{
    public class PreventChangingTabsTabControl : TabControl
    {
        private int _previousTab;

        public PreventChangingTabsTabControl()
        {
            SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!CanChangeTab)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    SelectedIndex = _previousTab;
                }
                else
                    _previousTab = SelectedIndex;
            };
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CanChangeTabProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CanChangeTab",
            typeof(Boolean),
            typeof(PreventChangingTabsTabControl)
        );

        public bool CanChangeTab
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(CanChangeTabProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CanChangeTabProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted compiles and runs fine without any exceptions. Is this the complete code?

Comment: @Rachel Not on my machine. You sure you left the IsAsync on "True"?

Comment: @UrbanEsc I copy/pasted the code directly from the question. I am using VS 2010 premium, .Net framework 4.0, and have a Windows XP machine.

Comment: @Rachel Yes, me too. Except i have a win7 machine, but i highly doubt that to be the reason. It compiles and runs perfect, yes, as soon as you click a tab twice however the exception of the OP pops up. You must be missing something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider a redesign of that window instead of introducing a heap of new problems by just trial-and-erroring on the "IsAsync" property of the binding.

I am not sure if a tab control will allow this level of control you seek. You could try to catch the event when someone tries to change the selected item, but you would not be able to cancel it out. There is a way however, see Option 4 if you dont want to read the other suggestions.

**Option 1: The custom control**

I would consider writing a bit of custom code that mimics the functionality of an item container. Its easy to achieve your desired behaviour this way. Just bind a command to the buttons (or whatever control you wish the user to click on), and return *CanExecute* with false if there are still changes to be submitted - or ask your user whatever you want when it gets executed, and only change the content displayed (ie your custom "TabItem") if desired.

**Option 2: Preventing the user by disabling the tabs**

Another way would be to bind the "IsEnabled" property of each of the tabitems to a dependency property on your viewmodel, that controls which of them is available to the user. Like, you know that the first page still needs work, just disable all the other ones meanwhile. But be aware that right now you are not creating any TabItems - your content are just plain strings.

```
public List<TabItem> ItemsSource { get; private set; }

....

ItemsSource = new List<TabItem> { new TabItem() { Header = "Foo", Content = "Foo" }, new TabItem() { Header = "Bar", Content = "Bar" }, new TabItem() { Header = "FooBar", Content = "FooBar" } };
```

Since you don't want to prevent the user doing something but rather would like to ask to save the changes, i'd go for the custom control route. Still there is option 3.

**Option 3: Popup window**

Use a popup window and ask to save changes if the user is finished with changing whatever is on that page and clicks on the "Close" button (rather than the "Save" button that should also reside on the same page ;) )

**Option 4: Check on StackOverflow**

Actually i did that for you, and here is a solution another user has found for the exact same problem: [WPF Tab Control Prevent Tab Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090392/wpf-tab-control-prevent-tab-change)
The reason why i didnt post that up-front was that i personally wouldnt do it that way because, man do i HATE applications that do this.

Here you go.

Comment: Thank you for these options. Option 3 is not possible because the tab would be a different one when the Popup window will be displayed. Option 1&2 will change the look&feel - I'm not sure about that one. Option 4 is indeed dirty ;)
Maybe I'll subclass the TabControl and use Option 4 in it.
Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: This works for me.  I redirect to another tab on certain conditions in the setter.  I really think you have  some other problems going on.  If you would post your code _selectedIndex = 1 AND your NotifyPropertyChanged I bet we could fix this.  I suspect you don't have a proper  NotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try actually implementing the SelectedIndex

```
    namespace TabControlOutOfRangeException
    {
        public partial class MainWindow  
        {
            public List<string> ItemsSource { get; private set; }
            private int selectedIndex

            public int SelectedIndex { 
                get { return selectedIndex; } 
                set { selecectedIndex = value; } }

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                ItemsSource = new List<string>{"Foo", "Bar", "FooBar"};

                DataContext = this;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the same, just more verbose. Changed nothing :(
Why should this have an impact?

Comment: The get was not returning any value and that might have been causing a problem.  If you want the UI to be aware of a change to a value then you need implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear, my question is: why does the code in the question-text throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to affect the TabControl the binding needs to be two-way, i.e. your code-behind needs to be able to notify the view that the property changed, for that you should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your window, e.g.

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

```
private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _selectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedIndex != value)
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Async bindings are usually for properties which have a long-running getter, with e.g. a database query, you should not need this here.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to change the SelectedIndex when I'm in the setter (for example, the user clicks on the tab). If the binding isn't asynchronous, the change of the SelectedIndex inside the setter does nothing.

Comment: Does this code posted by H.B. work.  It looks like it would do what you need.  Remove the IsAsych.

Comment: I do this exact same thing and it works for me.  You did implement NotifyPropertyChanged?  Please post your complete (revised) code with INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to to change the selectedIndex in the setter itself, then to get it updated on UI, you have to raise the property changed in an async manner like this -

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged

private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _selectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedIndex != value)
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChangedAsAsync("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChangedAsAsync(string propertyName)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate {  OnPropertyChanged(propertyName); }, DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, does not work. Still the same exception after changing the tab twice.

Comment: Have you removed the IsAsync property from your xaml as suggested by H.B?? Also can you tell the exact code, what you are doing in your setter of SelectedIndex?

Comment: A simplification of my problem would be to set _selectedIndex = 1 instead of _selectedIndex = value in the setter. If I remove IsAsync = True, no exception will be thrown - but it doesn't prevent changing the tab either.